# Find column match, then find cell match below, then extract value in same row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to find a formula that takes as inputs the age (in months) and pupil's long jump to find the respective mark. Please see attached image.

I've tried to use the combination of `INDEX(...., MATCH , MATCH)` without success as the values of the jump length are duplicated in the lookup_array.

I would appreciate some help to define the formula that retrieves the mark, many thanks.

[image: thumbnail linked to main image]

Comment: What should be the result if the exact input numbers don't exist in your table (e.g. 146 months or 148 month & 1.80 jump)? Please add your example also as text to help us using your data for finding the solution (you can convert your data to table formatting e.g. [here](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables))

Comment: If the person is 146, 144 is applicable until they reach 148, the same applies for the jumps, if a person jumps 1.80 we consider the surpassed length in the table, e.g. for a 154 month old person that jumps 1.8m, the mark shall be 6, as he is classified within 152 column and he has overtaken the 1.77m scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the index match you will need to flip the marks to be sorted lowest to highest.

Then use this formula:

```
=INDEX($B$8:$B$18,MATCH($C$3,INDEX($C$8:$F$18,0,MATCH($C$2,$C$7:$F$7))))
```

[image]

To deal with the fact that the pupil may be less than 144 months old use this:

```
=INDEX($B$8:$B$18,MATCH($C$3,INDEX($C$8:$F$18,0,IF($C$2<$C$7,1,MATCH($C$2,$C$7:$F$7)))))
```

Comment: I got your formula to work on the original data (with the marks sorted from highest to lowest) simply by adding a `-1` parameter to the first `MATCH` function.  (It gives different results — off by 1 — for jump values that fall between thresholds (rather than being *equal* to one of them), but the question doesn’t specify the desired behavior for that case.)

Comment: There is a small issue with this solution, for instance, if the pupil age is below 144 months the formula will default to 0. The desired behaviour would be to use the marks for 144 in this case. Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: see edit. @peterbasil